Habilitar pago con billetera de Mercado Pago en Checkout bricks
Hola estoy implementando checkout bricks en mi pagina web con el objetivo de procesar todos los medios de pago posibles en mi pagina sin necesidad de redirigirme o utilizar algun modal emergente.
Basandome en la referencia de mercado pago, el checkout bricks completo (con todos los bricks) deberia verse algo asi:

Sin embargo, cuando implemento en mi pagina utilizando las credenciales de prueba, el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

Solo aparecen esos 3 medios de pago, y no aparece la opcion de pagar con el dinero de la billetera de mercado pago.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

    const mp = new MercadoPago('TEST-e587cc71-b47f-4db3-b3cd-515433ee5d53', {
        locale: 'es-AR'
    });
    const bricksBuilder = mp.bricks();
    const renderPaymentBrick = async (bricksBuilder) => {
      const settings = {
        initialization: {
          /*
            "amount" es el monto total a pagar por todos los medios de pago con excepción de la Cuenta de Mercado Pago y Cuotas sin tarjeta de crédito, las cuales tienen su valor de procesamiento determinado en el backend a través del "preferenceId"
          */
          amount: 10000,
          preferenceId: "<PREFERENCE_ID>",
          payer: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
          },
        },
        customization: {
          visual: {
            style: {
              theme: "dark",
            },
          },
          paymentMethods: {
            creditCard: "all",
            debitCard: "all",
            ticket: "all",
            bankTransfer: "all",
            wallet_purchase: "all",
            maxInstallments: 9
          },
        },
        callbacks: {
          onReady: () => {
            /*
             Callback llamado cuando el Brick está listo.
             Aquí puede ocultar cargamentos de su sitio, por ejemplo.
            */
          },
          onSubmit: ({ selectedPaymentMethod, formData }) => {
            // callback llamado al hacer clic en el botón de envío de datos
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              fetch("/______desubik2/buy/php/process-payment.php", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
              })
                .then((response) => {
                  // recibir el resultado del pago
                 console.log(response.json());
                 resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // manejar la respuesta de error al intentar crear el pago
                  reject();
                });
            });
          },
          onError: (error) => {
            // callback llamado para todos los casos de error de Brick
            console.error(error);
          },
        },
      };
      window.paymentBrickController = await bricksBuilder.create(
        "payment",
        "paymentBrick_container",
        settings
      );
    };
    renderPaymentBrick(bricksBuilder);

Como se ve no estoy agregando ninguna PREFERENCE_ID, no se si esto tendrá algo que ver con el hecho de que no agrega la opcion de pago con dinero de mercado pago (entiendo que cuando se elige esta opcion, el procesamiento se hace utilizando la preferencia).
Sin embargo, también intente colocar una preference id creada previamente en PHP, pero el problema no se solucionó:
preferenceId: "<?= $preference->id ?>",

En la consola del navegador aparecen los siguientes mensajes:

... es como si la opción wallet_purchase no existiera, esto es lo que me deja más sorprendido.
Si alguno puede guiarme sobre como solucionarlo, o que alternativa hay, gracias de antemano. Saludos

Sin tener ni idea, estás seguro de que es wallet_purchase y no walletPurchase?? Porque es rarísimo que en una api uno de los parámetros no siga el estilo de nomenclatura de los demás... todo lo tienes en camelCase excepto ese que lo tienes en snake_case... es rarito

No lo había notado pero ahora que lo mencionas si es bastante raro, aunque acabo de probar poniendo walletPurchase y nada. En la documentacion de mercado pago usa wallet_purchase .

Solucionado, buscando más a fondo en la documentación de mercado pago, parece que han actualizado el parámetro que anteriormente se llamaba wallet_purchase. Ahora se llama mercadoPago:
paymentMethods: {
   creditCard: "all",
   debitCard: "all",
   ticket: "all",
   bankTransfer: "all",
   mercadoPago: "all",   // <--------
   maxInstallments: 9
},

Hay que tener cuidado porque la documentación si se encuentra un poco desactualizada.
PD: Tuve que cargar además una PREFERENCE_ID de prueba para que funcione.
